# React-Native, Save Data in Modal Class

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-Native.
I am able to parse my json data from server, but I want to save those data in a modal class, like we do in iOS using NSObject Class.

Can any one help me with this, where I can parse json data and store all those data in a modal class and after that store that modal class in UserDefaults.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you need to save data in modal class, take a state array and save json response in that array

Comment: Hello Paras, Thanks for your response. I want to save data in modal class because I want to pass data from one component to another on button click. Hence I want to pass the object of whole modal class, which will be easy for me. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: You can also pass that state array from one component to another that is not a problem

Comment: Yes, I can do this but when I have a dictionary with data like, firstName, lastName, address and i want to save all those data. Then what should be my approach in such case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json response like this

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                arrayName: [],

            }
        }


return fetch('url')
            .then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    arrayName: responseJson,
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```